# Timeout en Actividad web en Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, data

Al realizar una actividad web en Azure Data Factory, si tarda más de 1 minuto en enviar la respuesta da error.

¿Hay alguna forma de aumentar ese *timeout*?

Gracias

Comment: Hola Inma, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir algo más de información y código a ser posible (p.e. la definición de la actividad). También sería ideal que indicaras lo que has investigado e intentado. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: creo que el maximo es 230 segundos, por lo demas entiendo no se puede aumentar el tiempo en azure, este articulo te podra ayudar: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05f254a6-9b34-4eb2-a5f7-2a82fb40135f/time-out-after-230-seconds?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview